# Paths not matching on map, while they do in Illustrator

Tags: leaflet, geojson, kml, illustrator, mapublisher

I'm quite a newcomer when it comes to map data.

I have an Illustrator map, drawn by myself, with different polygons (regions, country, ...).
In Illustrator I know 100% that the region and country line are perfectly in the same position.

[image]

I then used MAPublisher to export these to KML files, to then convert them into GeoJSON files.

I use these GeoJSON files together with Leaflet to generate polygons in the shape of what I have drawn in Illustrator.

But as you can see in the following picture, when I zoom in, the lines of regions and country are not in the same position.

[image]

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: You're following a very convoluted path to get to your output, the fault could lie with any package along the way. If I were to take a wild stab in the dark I'd say that your coordinate reference system isn't quite right, KML is always WGS84/Geographic when exporting from illustrator your origin point is most likely different. You would avoid many of these sort of problems if you drafted the original in a GIS aware system like QGIS. From here I can only suggest to warp your data separately to known to be accurate set of control points.

Comment: I will look into this, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using two different CRS (Coordinate Reference System) in Illustrator and in leaflet. You should check this, and, is not an error, you are using two different ways to represent the World.